'Run-time error 1004, Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed when overwriting cells of particular cell reference
I have two columns, one with a list of cell references (P), one with text (Q). I am trying to get the text to be put in the particular cell reference from a macro.
Sub OverwriteCellReferencesWithNames()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim nameCell As Range
    Dim cellRef As String
    
    ' Set worksheet reference to Sheet1
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    ' Clear the contents of the specified ranges
    ws.Range("B4:F8").ClearContents
    ws.Range("B11:F15").ClearContents
    
    ' Loop through each cell in column P
    For Each cell In ws.Range("P2:P" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Row)
        ' Get the cell reference from column P
        
        cellRef = cell.Value
        
        ' Find the corresponding name in column Q
        Set nameCell = ws.Cells(cell.Row, "Q")
        
        ' If a corresponding name is found in column Q, overwrite the cell reference in column P with the name

        If Not nameCell Is Nothing Then
            ws.Range(cellRef).Value = nameCell.Value
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub

The code throws

Run-time error 1004, Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed

on
ws.Range(cellRef).Value = nameCell.Value

I tried error checking to force the code to only work when the format of cellRef is appropriate ie. a string with a proper cell address. I expected this to exit the for loop when it discovered a cell with no text.

ws.Range requires a cell reference, address, and your variable nameCell passes the cell content, not the address.


If cellRef is not a valid reference string (eg. ZZZ1), it raises 1004.
nameCell is a cell on Col Q in your code. So If Not nameCell Is Nothing  Then is always evaluated as True.

Sub OverwriteCellReferencesWithNames()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim sName As String
    Dim cellRef As String
    Dim cellTarget As Range
    ' Set worksheet reference to Sheet1
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    ' Clear the contents of the specified ranges
    ws.Range("B4:F8").ClearContents
    ws.Range("B11:F15").ClearContents
    
    ' Loop through each cell in column P
    For Each cell In ws.Range("P2:P" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Row)
        Set cellTarget = Nothing
        ' Get the cell reference from column P
        cellRef = cell.Value
        sName = cell.Offset(, 1).Value ' get name in Col Q
        ' If a corresponding name is found in column Q, overwrite the cell reference in column P with the name
        If Len(sName) > 0 Then
            On Error Resume Next
            Set cellTarget = ws.Range(cellRef)
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Not cellTarget Is Nothing Then
                cellTarget.Value = sName
                Exit For ' modify as needed
            Else
                MsgBox cellRef & " is not a valid cell ref."
            End If
        Else
            ' name is blank
            ' your code as needed
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub



Populate Cells Defined By References in a Column With Corresponding Values From Another Column
Sub OverwriteCellReferencesWithNames()
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        
        .Range("B4:F8").ClearContents
        .Range("B11:F15").ClearContents
        
        Dim RefData() As Variant, NameData() As Variant

        ' The simplifications in the following With statement assume at least
        ' two rows of data i.e. at least one cell below 'P2' must not be empty.
        With .Range("P2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp))
            RefData = .Value
            NameData = .EntireRow.Columns("Q").Value
        End With
    
        Dim dcell As Range, dName As Variant, r As Long
            
        For r = 1 To UBound(NameData, 1)
            dName = NameData(r, 1)
            If Not IsError(dName) Then ' name is not an error
                If Len(dName) > 0 Then ' name is not blank
                    On Error Resume Next
                        Set dcell = .Range(RefData(r, 1))
                    On Error GoTo 0
                    If Not dcell Is Nothing Then ' valid cell reference
                        dcell.Value = dName
                        Set dcell = Nothing
                    'Else ' invalid cell reference; do nothing
                    End If
                'Else ' name is blank; do nothing
                End If
            'Else ' name is an error; do nothing
            End If
        Next r

    End With

End Sub

